# Having trouble with macros in C++

Tags: c++, class, macros

I'm trying to write a C++ macro to define a bunch of sub-classes using a template and a color name like so:

```
#define DECLARE_SET_ELEMENT(color) class ##color##SetElement : public SetElement { public: ##color##SetElement(std::string name); int getValue() override; };
```

so that I can use it like:

```
DECLARE_SET_ELEMENT(Blue) // -> class BlueSetElement ...
DECLARE_SET_ELEMENT(Red)  // -> class RedSetElement ...
...
```

But the macro definition does not seem to be working correctly. How should it be in order for it to work as I am intending?

Comment: Why don't you actually use a template? This is literally what they're for.

Comment: Yes, we'd need more context but macros seem like a weird choice. Likely, you rather want to inherit from a common base class.

Comment: It does inherit a common base class, hence the `class ... : public SetElement` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
#define DECLARE_SET_ELEMENT(color) class color##SetElement : public SetElement { public: color##SetElement(std::string name); int getValue() override; };
```

instead. Leading `##` are not suitable in this case. You don't want to combine the `class` keyword with `color`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! :)

Comment: It is stronger than 'there is no need for the leading `##`'; there is an absolute requirement to omit the leading `##` because that combines the token `class` with the colour argument and `SetElement`, leading to wholly broken C++ syntax.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Changed the answer accordingly.